# In my React Project Router doesn't work well

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Would you please help me solve my problem in my react router?
I have made three pages: App.js index.js Main.js, and some pages at y src/pages as Home, About, Contact,...

index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Header from "./header";
import Footer from "./footer";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
     <Navbar />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Main.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./pages/aboutus";
import Contact from "./pages/contactus";
import Services from "./pages/depressionadults";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Header from "./header";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Footer from "./footer";

export default function Main() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Header />
    <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />}>
          <Route path="/pages/depressionadults" element={<Services />} />
          <Route path="/pages/App" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/pages/contactus" element={<Contact />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

But just URL address changes and nothing happens about loading the components I've addressed to. It seems that App.js is not necessary and I should render `<Main />` directly, but when I clear it nothing works at all. If I should do any changes in my index.html too?

I expect my Router works well, and I cannot find out where is the problem?

Comment: "It seems that App.js is not necessary and I should render `<Main />` directly" - sounds like you know what the issue is. `Main` has the router, routes, and routed content you want to render. You might want to delete `App` and rename `Main` to `App`. Can you clarify what the issue is? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Yes by searching I guess it, but I wondered why it doesn't work when I delete the content and the refers to App.js. Yes, When I click the links of other components like home, contact, etc, the url changes but the content of that pages doesn't load and I remain at the main page.

Comment: What is the "main page"? Searching *what*? Deleted *what* content and *what* refers to `App.js`? Can you [edit] to include all the relevant code you are working with? The components with the links you are interacting with, and the routed components you are trying to render on each route?

Comment: Thank you so much. I deleted App.js and the next error was just because of BrowseRouter in Navbar and Footer.

Comment: Can you clarify what next error you are referring to?

Comment: Because of the links I had in my Nabar and Footer, I had to have <BrowserRouter></BrowserRouter> there too, and It resulted in error.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit. You mentioned an error, I was asking for you to provide details on what the error actually was/is, which would likely include a code stacktrace which would also inform readers *where* in the code the error occurs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong component,
put `<Main/>` component instead of `<App/>` in `index.js` file.

Comment: But now when I put <Main /> instead of <App /> I get this error:

Comment: caught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app.

Comment: I find it out. It was because of the BrowserRouter in my Navbar and Footer. Thank you so very much.